# AWS Lambda Application Layer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to create a [layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) from an [AWS Lambda Application](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/deploying-lambda-apps.html) and reference that layer from another AWS Lambda Application.

I have the first application creating the layer.

Application template.yml

[image: template.yml]

index.js for layer

[image]

Layer in AWS Console

[image]

Zip of the layer

[image]

When I reference the layer from my other application I get the following build error.

[image]

template.yml for other application
[image]

I am able to add the layer to the lambda through the aws console.

[image]

[image]

What's the correct way to reference this layer from the template.yml?

Update - debug output

> sam local start-lambda --debug
> 2021-12-16 21:39:37,696 | Telemetry
> endpoint configured to be
> https://aws-serverless-tools-telemetry.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/metrics
> 2021-12-16 21:39:37,696 | Using config file: samconfig.toml, config
> environment: default 2021-12-16 21:39:37,696 | Expand command line
> arguments to: 2021-12-16 21:39:37,696 |
> --template_file=C:\Users\bensi\IdeaProjects\tu-record\template.yml --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3001 --layer_cache_basedir=C:\Users\bensi\ AppData\Roaming\AWS SAM\layers-pkg --container_host=localhost
> --container_host_interface=127.0.0.1  2021-12-16 21:39:37,949 | local start_lambda command is called 2021-12-16 21:39:37,955 | Collected
> default values for parameters: {} 2021-12-16 21:39:37 Plugin
> 'ServerlessAppPlugin' raised an exception: 'list' object has no
> attribute 'get' Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Program
> Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samtranslator\plugins_*init*_.py",
> line 133, in act
> getattr(plugin, method_name)(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samtranslator\metrics\method_decorator.py",
> line 96, in wrapper_cw_timer
> exec_result = func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samtranslator\plugins\application\serverless_app_plugin.py", line 92, in on_before_transfor m_template
> for logical_id, app in template.iterate({SamResourceType.Application.value}):   File
> "C:\Program
> Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samtranslator\sdk\template.py",
> line 33, in iterate
> resource = SamResource(resource_dict)   File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samtranslator\sdk\resource.py",
> line 24, in **init**
> self.type = resource_dict.get("Type") AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get' 2021-12-16 21:39:37,973 | Sending
> Telemetry: {'metrics': [{'commandRun': {'requestId':
> 'd4aa74c5-a627-407e-8f65-f86fa97eeb15', 'installationId':
> 'e4cd6d85-622f
> -47df-8c87-08d5d6c395d6', 'sessionId': '80147f0f-42ce-4539-9edd-f08dd86eebcf', 'executionEnvironment': 'CLI',
> 'ci': False, 'pyversion': '3.8.8', 'samcliVersion ': '1.36.0',
> 'awsProfileProvided': False, 'debugFlagProvided': True, 'region': '',
> 'commandName': 'sam local start-lambda', 'duration': 277,
> 'exitReason': 'Att ributeError', 'exitCode': 255}}]} 2021-12-16
> 21:39:38,176 | Telemetry response: 200 Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File "runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main   File
> "runpy.py", line 87, in *run_code   File "C:\Program
> Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli_*main**.py",
> line 12, in 
> cli(prog_name="sam")   File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line
> 829, in **call**
> return self.main(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line
> 782, in main
> rv = self.invoke(ctx)   File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line
> 1259, in invoke
> return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))   File "C:\Program
> Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line
> 1259, in invoke
> return *process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))   File "C:\Program
> Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line
> 1066, in invoke
> return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)   File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line
> 610, in invoke
> return callback(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py",
> line 73, in new_func
> return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line
> 610, in invoke
> return callback(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\telemetry\metric.py",
> line 157, in wrapped
> raise exception  # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type   File "C:\Program
> Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\telemetry\metric.py",
> line 122, in wrapped   File "C:\Program
> Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\providers\sam_stack_provider.py",
> line 51, in **init**
> self.*template_dict = self.get_template(   File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\providers\sam_base_provider.py",
> line 189, in get_template
> template_dict = SamTranslatorWrapper(template_dict, parameter_values=parameters_values).run_plugins()   File "C:\Program
> Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\samlib\wrapper.py",
> line 68, in run_plugins
> parser.parse(template_copy, all_plugins)  # parse() will run all configured plugins   File "C:\Program
> Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\samlib\wrapper.py",
> line 88, in parse
> sam_plugins.act(LifeCycleEvents.before_transform_template, sam_template)   File "C:\Program
> Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samtranslator\plugins_*init**.py",
> line 139, in act
> raise ex   File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samtranslator\plugins_*init**.py",
> line 133, in act
> getattr(plugin, method_name)(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samtranslator\metrics\method_decorator.py",
> line 96, in wrapper_cw_timer
> exec_result = func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samtranslator\plugins\application\serverless_app_plugin.py", line 92, in on_before_transfor m_template
> for logical_id, app in template.iterate({SamResourceType.Application.value}):   File
> "C:\Program
> Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samtranslator\sdk\template.py",
> line 33, in iterate
> resource = SamResource(resource_dict)   File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samtranslator\sdk\resource.py",
> line 24, in **init**
> self.type = resource_dict.get("Type") AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: can you run your command with `--debug` option and share the output

Comment: @Ruben The build fail before the lambda deploys so when I run the command it runs the version prior to the layer change

Comment: so after the build phase it run the ` aws cloufomation` package, can you alter your template and add the `--debug`  in it?

Comment: @Ruben nm, i found out how to get the debug output. I update my question

Answer (score 1):

`Layer` in your application template is expecting list Dictionary but its getting list because of `-` that could be the reason.[need to do more analysis]

Meanwhile, I suggest you use the below method to include the layer in your application

```js
MyLayer:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::LayerVersion
  Properties:
    CompatibleRuntimes:
      - nodejs12.x
    Content:
      S3Bucket: <your-bucket-name>
      S3Key: layer.zip
    Description: My layer
    LayerName: my-layer
    LicenseInfo: MIT
```

Comment: Do I need to zip and upload the layer to an s3 bucket? I see the layer in the aws console, but there isn't anything saved in s3 that I can find. Maybe I can automate the zipping and uploading to s3 as part of the pipeline once i get it working.

Comment: I added an update to the question. I'm able to manually add the layer to my lambda through the aws console. i just want to do that through the template.yml cloudformation configurations

Comment: when you created layer you probably use either s3 or local .zip to create it right?
I suggest you upload your zip file to S3 and use it in your template and attach it to your lambda function as show in this article [Refer Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html)

Comment: The first screenshot shows the template.yml that creates the layer for me. I can get this to work manually, but I want to avoid manually zipping files and manually managing an s3 bucket. I can include the layer that is created by the template.yml by manually including it in my lambda through the aws console, but i want to do that by configuration instead.

Comment: I assume had it working now. I am only aware to two methods to create the lambda layers

Answer (score 1):

I needed to move the `Layers:` config in the `template.yml` under the lambda resource and replace `$LATEST` with a hardcoded reference to the version.

```
Resources:
  record:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Layers:
        - arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:501480421890:layer:testing-layers:7
```

Comment: Can you share the reference which suggested thi method of moving the layer into the Resource section

Comment: @Ruben https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/blob/master/sample-apps/blank-nodejs/template.yml#L20

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#invocation-layers-cloudformation

Answer (score 0):

If you have the custom layer and the lambda function in different SAM templates, try this approach:

```
Resources:
   MyCustomLayer:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
        Properties:
            LayerName: my-test-layer
            Description: 
            ContentUri: src
            CompatibleRuntimes:
              - nodejs14.x
            RetentionPolicy: Retain
        Metadata:
             BuildMethod: nodejs14.x

Outputs:
  MyCustomLayer:
    Description: "Shared layer"
    Value: !Ref MyCustomLayer
    Export:
      Name: !Sub MyCustomLayer
```

Use the Layer reference in the Lambda in the second template:

```
Layers:
    - Fn::ImportValue:
       !Sub MyCustomLayer
```

If you have both the layer & lambda in the same stack, then simply use the !Ref to dynamically use ARN instead of hardcoding the version

```
Layers:
 - !Ref LayerNameInSAMTemplate
```